# Flink Streaming Compression not working using Amazon AWS S3 connector (StreamingFileSink with CompressWriterFactory)

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-flink, flink-streaming

When I run Apache Flink streaming to AWS S3 as a Sink, the standard version (forRowFormat)
works fine.

```
StreamingFileSink<String> s3sink = StreamingFileSink
        .forRowFormat(new Path(s3Url),
                (String element, OutputStream stream) -> {
                    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(stream);
                    out.println(element);
                })
            .withBucketAssigner(new BucketAssigner())
            .withRollingPolicy(DefaultRollingPolicy.builder()
                    .withMaxPartSize(100)
                    .withRolloverInterval(30000)
                    .build())
            .withBucketCheckInterval(100)
            .build();
```

When I run the same thing with bulk format and CompressWriterFactory

```
StreamingFileSink<String> s3sink = StreamingFileSink
        .forBulkFormat(new Path(s3Url), 
                new CompressWriterFactory(new DefaultExtractor()))
        .withOutputFileConfig(outputFileConfig)
        .build();
```

it gives me below error.

(Note - CompressWriterFactory works fine with HDFS scheme 'hdfs://host:port/path')

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: S3RecoverableFsDataOutputStream cannot sync state to S3. Use persist() to create a persistent recoverable intermediate point.
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3.common.utils.RefCountedBufferingFileStream.sync(RefCountedBufferingFileStream.java:112)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3.common.writer.S3RecoverableFsDataOutputStream.sync(S3RecoverableFsDataOutputStream.java:126)
    at org.apache.flink.formats.compress.writers.NoCompressionBulkWriter.finish(NoCompressionBulkWriter.java:56)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.BulkPartWriter.closeForCommit(BulkPartWriter.java:62)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Bucket.closePartFile(Bucket.java:239)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Bucket.prepareBucketForCheckpointing(Bucket.java:280)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Bucket.onReceptionOfCheckpoint(Bucket.java:253)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Buckets.snapshotActiveBuckets(Buckets.java:250)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Buckets.snapshotState(Buckets.java:241)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.StreamingFileSink.snapshotState(StreamingFileSink.java:422)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.functions.StreamingFunctionUtils.trySnapshotFunctionState(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:118)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.functions.StreamingFunctionUtils.snapshotFunctionState(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:99)
    ...
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runMailboxLoop(StreamTask.java:487)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:470)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:707)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:532)
```

> Notes -
>
> 1. Flink Version 1.10.0
> 2. s3Url = "s3a://bucket/folder/path";

Answer (score 1):

Just discovered a workaround for this issue: specifying the Hadoop compression codec:

```
CompressWriters.forExtractor(new DefaultExtractor()).withHadoopCompression("GzipCodec")
```

Answer (score 0):

this seems like a bug. You can open a JIRA with the description you include here.