# Flink Table API streaming S3 sink throws SerializedThrowable exception

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-table-api

I am trying to write a simple table API S3 streaming sink (csv format) using flink 1.15.1 and I am facing the following exception,

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.SerializedThrowable: S3RecoverableFsDataOutputStream cannot sync state to S3. Use persist() to create a persistent recoverable intermediate point.
at org.apache.flink.fs.s3.common.utils.RefCountedBufferingFileStream.sync(RefCountedBufferingFileStream.java:111) ~[flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.15.1.jar:1.15.1]
at org.apache.flink.fs.s3.common.writer.S3RecoverableFsDataOutputStream.sync(S3RecoverableFsDataOutputStream.java:129) ~[flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.15.1.jar:1.15.1]
at org.apache.flink.formats.csv.CsvBulkWriter.finish(CsvBulkWriter.java:110) ~[flink-csv-1.15.1.jar:1.15.1]
at org.apache.flink.connector.file.table.FileSystemTableSink$ProjectionBulkFactory$1.finish(FileSystemTableSink.java:642) ~[flink-connector-files-1.15.1.jar:1.15.1]
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.BulkPartWriter.closeForCommit(BulkPartWriter.java:64) ~[flink-file-sink-common-1.15.1.jar:1.15.1]
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Bucket.closePartFile(Bucket.java:263) ~[flink-streaming-java-1.15.1.jar:1.15.1]
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Bucket.prepareBucketForCheckpointing(Bucket.java:305) ~[flink-streaming-java-1.15.1.jar:1.15.1]
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Bucket.onReceptionOfCheckpoint(Bucket.java:277) ~[flink-streaming-java-1.15.1.jar:1.15.1]
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Buckets.snapshotActiveBuckets(Buckets.java:270) ~[flink-streaming-java-1.15.1.jar:1.15.1]
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Buckets.snapshotState(Buckets.java:261) ~[flink-streaming-java-1.15.1.jar:1.15.1]
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.StreamingFileSinkHelper.snapshotState(StreamingFileSinkHelper.java:87) ~[flink-streaming-java-1.15.1.jar:1.15.1]
at org.apache.flink.connector.file.table.stream.AbstractStreamingWriter.snapshotState(AbstractStreamingWriter.java:129) ~[flink-connector-files-1.15.1.jar:1.15.1]
```

In my config, I am trying to read from Kafka and write to S3 (s3a) using table API and checkpoint configuration using s3p (presto). Even I tried with a simple `datagen` example instead of Kafka and I am getting the same issue. I think I am following all the exact steps mentioned in the docs and the above exceptions are not much helpful. Exactly it is failing when the code triggers the checkpoint but I don't have any clue after this. Could someone please help me to understand what I am missing here? I don't find any open issue with such logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug. I've raised it [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-28513) (after discussing with the community). Sadly I am not able to find any work around for Table API S3 CSV streaming sink. Similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62138635/flink-streaming-compression-not-working-using-amazon-aws-s3-connector-streaming) for DataStreamAPI with a workaround.